# Using awk's ~ operator

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I'm having trouble with a basic search function that I'm working on bash.

Basically, I have a $file="Books.txt" and in it I have values separated by colon:

```
C++ Programming for Dummies:Bob:60:50:20
Catch Me If You Can: Mary Ann:40:30:20
```

The first 2 columns are titles and authors respectively. I'm trying to search by the titles of the books.

```
read -p "Title: " searchTitle
```

So far I have this code:

```
awk -v findTitle="$searchTitle" 'BEGIN {FS=":"; OFS=", ";} $1 ~ findTitle {print $1, $2, "$"$3, $4, $5}' $file
```

It works if I typed "Catch" in the prompt - Output:

```
Catch Me If You Can, Mary Ann, $40, 30, 20
```

However, If I searched for "C++", it gives me both -

```
Catch Me If You Can, Mary Ann, $40, 30, 20
C++ Programming for Dummies, Bob, $60, 50, 20
```

My question is: Why? I should be getting only the 'C++' book as a result. Is there other ways to get to the expected output? I tried to find answers but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide if you want to support regular expressions in your search or not. In any case you must use read `-r` flag to keep it from interpreting escape sequences and instead reading them as literal text.

If you want to search for fixed strings instead of patterns, use the `index()` function in awk:

```
read -r -p "Title: " searchTitle
awk -F: -v OFS=", " -v search="$searchTitle" '
    index($1,search) {
        print $1, $2, "$"$3, $4, $5
    }
' books.txt
```

If you want to support regular expressions, the code should look like this:

```
read -r -p "Title: " searchTitle
awk -F: -v OFS=", " -v search="$searchTitle" '
    $1 ~ search {
        print $1, $2, "$"$3, $4, $5
    }
' books.txt
```

However, you need to escape special regex characters in the case they appear in the pattern. The `+` from `C++` is such a special character.

Since the strings get's parsed twice, once by the shell and once by `awk`, you need to double escape it:

```
Title: C\\+\\+
```

Comment: This solved the problem! Thank you Sir! Ill looked more into the awk's manual from now on

Comment: Consider whether or not the search should be case-sensitive and, if not, then apply `tolower()` to both sides of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the rvalue of the ~ operator is supposed to be a regular expression and `+` in a regex has a special meaning (it's a quantifier: *one or more times*).

So it matches the C from "Catch" and the C from "C++" since they have one or more C.

if you want to search the literal string "C++" you must write "`C\+\+`"

Comment: Ah.. Thank you kind Sir! One more thing, if so, how should I go about in improving this code so that I get the expected output?

Comment: @AdamWinfield: you only need to escape special characters like + in your search string. Take a look at hek2mgl answer, that doesn't need to use the ~ operator. I think it's more appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The funny thing is, that without `read -r`, you would need to type `C\\\\+\\\\+` :D